# I am getting non breaking space as a text when scraping website span

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, jsdom

I scrapeed a website and got essential text but it's also giving non breaking space with the text anyway I can remove those nbsp? Here is the generated output by console :-

```
Action&nbsp;/&nbsp;Adventure&nbsp;/&nbsp;Harem&nbsp;/&nbsp;Post-apocalyptic World
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using:

```js
var r_tag = tags.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
```

I was using `&nbsp` instead of `/&nbsp`